# Flutter windows application with printing causes low memory issue

Tags: windows, thermal-printer, flutter-desktop, escpos, flutter-windows

We developed a Flutter windows desktop application for POS machines. One of the main feature is printing bills. We used https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer library which prints but, after printing 100+ bills the windows shows low memory alert and system hangs. While checking task manager it is found that committed memory use increases while printing and when it hits the maximum, system hangs. Please help to find a solution.